# Why am I getting error "Call to a member function getInvoiceID() on boolean" in PHP?

Tags: boolean-operations

[image]

Hi. I would like to know the theory behind why this error occurs.

"Call to a member function getInvoiceID() on boolean".

Is it because the datatype does not match with the returned function getInvoiceID()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is because you called `getInvoiceID()` on an boolean, not an object. Check your variable assignment, it may be caused by a function that return boolean on fail instead of object. Please provide your code.

Comment: Thanks men sorry for the late response. This was resolved long time ago.